# Can Ninject 'Get' method cache value?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject

When i create MyClass with `Ninject`:

```
var myClass=kernel.Get<MyClass>();
```

Does `Ninject` create new object (or returns old) when i call?:

```
var myClass1=kernel.Get<MyClass>();
```

So, Ninject creates two objects:

```
if(myClass!=myClass1) //true
  {}
```

But can i get a cached object by Ninject?

Comment: Ninject's default scope is Transient Scope. So yes, calling `Get<T>()` twice will return two different objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [Ninject Object Scopes](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Object-Scopes) for more information.
For example, if you need only one object for type, you can register it in `SingletonScope`:

`kernel.Bind<Shogun>().ToSelf().InSingletonScope();`

There is other scope variations. If you are working with `ASP.NET`, most likely you want to register and cache your objects within `RequestScope`. Or you always can create custom scopes for advanced caching rules.

Answer (score 2):

What you seem to look for is called scope.
Please refer to the corresponding section in [Ninject documentation](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Object-Scopes)

> Ninject makes it easy to re-use instances that are already created,
>   without having to implement anything via code. All you need to do is
>   tell Ninject to Bind the class in a singleton scope.
>
> There are four built-in scopes available in Ninject, and a number of
>   others delivered via Extensions...